# Outputting Input from Line-In Input on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I have a project where I need to output through the device's speakers the input that comes in through either a line-in input, or an accessory connected to the 30-pin connector. Whilst working on the line-in input, I'm finding it hard to detect whether there is input from line-in, and how to get the input from this source and then replay the buffer through the speaker. Trying to get the property of kAudioSessionProperty_InputSource(s) for example is returning nothing.

Comment: Which iOS version?  There appears to be no API to support doing this on iOS 5.1 and older.

Comment: That might make a good question for Apple's devforums where beta OS discussions seem to be allowed by the developer agreement.